# init(coder) or awakeFromNib not called from view in storyboard - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a obj-c based project. Added a swift class:

```
@objc public class LabeledTimer: UIView

//MARK: Initializers
override init()
{
    super.init()
    self.setupSubviewUI()
}

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setupSubviewUI()
}

override public func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setupSubviewUI()
}
```

Added it in the storyboard:

[image]

Set the class for the view:

[image]

And yet none of my initializers are ever hit with a breakpoint when the app is run:

[image]

I am, ahem, swiftly losing my mind. Save me.

Comment: Did you change the class of the view in IB to LabeledTimer?

Comment: Yes, that is the second image

Comment: Do you get any message in the console? When I tried your code, I got a "unrecognized class in IB LabeledTimer" message. If I deleted the @objc from you code, changed the class in IB to UIView, then back again to LabeledTimer, it worked, and initWithCoder and awakeFromNib were called.

Comment: Wow Swift. I didn't delete "@objc" but I did change the class to UIView, build, and then back to LabeledTimer and it worked. Feel free to enter as an answer since you lead me down that route.